# JavaFX displaying scalable vector graphics?

Tags: java, svg, javafx, graphics, fxml

I want to include sth like a logo or a header/banner into my window. I possibly want to avoid using png/jpg Images, because this could look weird when my application runs on high res displays. So i created my banner as an svg. How can i insert this into my window? I know that it isn't possible to include it with the ImageView class of javafx, but i heard about the possibility to compose an svgpath-group in fxml/css and then load it via fxmlloader. But how do i do this whith all things like color gradients, ...? How do i have to compose my java/fxml document to show a scalable banner?

Answer (score 2):

There are various options do do this. I gave you a hint to the first one already in your previous question. (Use e(fx)clipse and convert the SVG to an FXML file.) This also handles all the color and gradient issues.

Another option is to use this little library https://github.com/codecentric/javafxsvg which makes it possible to treat any SVG image in the same way as a regular JavaFX image. It is rendered internally and can thus be adapted to any size or resolution change.